# Why are Kansas and Arkansas pronounced differently?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, historical-change

*Arkansas* is typically pronounced like so:

> “ahr-kuhn-saw”   IPA: `[ˈɑɹkənˌsɔː]`

However, *Kansas* is typically pronounced like this:

> “kan-zuhs”             IPA: `[ˈkænzɨs]`

Why are these two words that are so similar in spelling pronounced so differently?

Both are apparently linked to “Native American” origins. So what’s the difference in the original usages?

Comment: This is something I have often wondered and I hope there is an American out there who can give us the answer.

Comment: Does the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas#Etymology) not answer this?

Comment: Why are _Waltham_ and _Chatham_ not pronounced the same? Why don't _cough_ and _tough_ rhyme?

Comment: I think the question is back-to-front: it should be, why are they spelled the same.

Comment: Gaston is precisely right. The question as stated makes no sense. Spoken language is primary. You do not pronounce written language, you write down spoken language. And spelling is always an approximation and a compromise. And as J.R. points out, you get any number of word pairs where the spelling matches but not the pronunciation. Even *history* and *historical* represent completely different pronunciations, not to mention *object* (noun) and *object* (verb). So it is not clear why you picked this particular word pair in the first place.

Comment: @KronoS  Basically because  Kansas and Arkansas are based on different Algoquian exonyms for the Siouan tribes of the regions, *kanza* for the Kaw (in KS) and *akakaze* for the Quapaw (in AR). Arkansas is based on the *French* pronounciation of akakaze. Cf also the French spelling *Ouichita* in AR and the English *Wichita* in KS.

Comment: @Mario, where the Arkansas River flows through Wichita, KS, the residents pronounce the river name like R-Kansas ... perhaps quite a few other Kansas residents do the same ...

Comment: @jwpat7 Makes sense, Kansas is English, Arkansa(s) is Anglo-French, kinda :)

Comment: @jwpat7 And where in flows through Colorado, its origin point, we pronounce the Arkansas River as we do the state, with a -saw at the end.

Comment: @tchrist, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_River#Pronunciations)'s ambivalent on that point: “Many people in midwestern states, including Kansas and Colorado, pronounce [the river name] /ɑrˈkænzəs/ *ar-KAN-zəs*, while many other people in Colorado and Arkansas typically pronounce it /ˈɑrkənsɔː/ *AR-kən-saw* according to a state law passed in 1881”

Comment: @jwpat7 Um, Colorado is *not* a midwestern state. :)

Comment: Wow I must admit. This appears to have been more controversial than I thought it'd be.